# Getting Started with KnowRob

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was read at Getting Started at KnowRob Wiki
1-I try this command,

```
svn co svn+ssh://svn@svnradig/knowledge/trunk/owl ~/work/owl
```

actually I do not expect what should the output be
but it seems that I have a problem

2- please any explain to that command parts

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ svn co svn+ssh://svn@svnradig/knowledge/trunk/owl ~/work/owl
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48687/getting-started-with-knowrob/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-21**:
Ok thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The page you probably got this URL from is filed under "Deprecated" in the wiki. "Deprecated" means that the information is outdated and you should not use it unless you know what you are doing. There is plenty of documentation for getting started with KnowRob (which I guess you know already, given your other posts).

The URL only works in our internal network, which can also be seen by the missing global domain of the host 'svnradig'. The links Lorenz posted are those that should be used.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where did you find this command? The official [knowrob basics page](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:_KnowRob_basics) doesn't tell you anything about checking out a repository from svnradig. Have a look at [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob) for install instructions or install knowrob's debian package with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4